# Issue with switch statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

i currently have this code

My problem is that when i give a number 1 or 2, it doesn't give it and just says 'Not valid input'.

It would be nice if anyone could explain me why is it happening.

Thanks for any answer.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintStream;

 public class Screen {
    private static BufferedReader stdin;
    private static PrintStream os;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

      try {  
          stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.exit(1);
      }

     try {
        switch (Integer.parseInt(selectAction())) {
        case 1:
           os.println("1");
           System.err.print("Hello World ");   
           break;
        case 2:
           os.println("2");
           System.err.print("Another Word ");   
           break;
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("not valid input");
     }

   }

   public static String selectAction() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("1. Hello World.");
        System.out.println("2. Another Word.");
        System.out.print("\nMake selection: ");

        return stdin.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really look into proper exception handling.

Comment: You are probably getting a `NullPointerException` due to `os` being `null`.

Comment: As Soitrios pointed out, print the stack trace. That would tell you what's going wrong here.

Comment: You should also properly format your code. Not only will it be easier for you to read, but it will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: You declare `os` but **never** initialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide an initialization for `os` to prevent the `NullPointerException`. Your code works if I change the `os` declaration like

```
private static PrintStream os = System.out;
```

Also, **please** don't swallow the `Exception`

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("not valid input: " + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```